# What is an alternative to using subqueries in this SQL query that will give us better performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a Transact-SQL query that contains subqueries in the where section.   Inner Join gives unwanted results of adding tOrderDetails fields multiple times so we resorted to the (poor performance) sub queries.   It is timing out often.  We need the same result but with better performance.  Any suggestions?

```
SELECT sum (cast(Replace(tOrders.TotalCharges,'$','') as money)) as TotalCharges
FROM [ArtistShare].[dbo].tOrders
WHERE tOrders.isGiftCardRedemption = 0
  and tOrders.isTestOrder=0
  and tOrders.LastDateUpdate between @startDate and @endDate
  and (SELECT count(tORderDetails.ID)
       from tORderDetails
       where tORderDetails.ORderID = tORders.ORderID
         and tOrderDetails.isPromo=1) = 0
  and (SELECT top 1 tProjects.ProjectReleaseDt
       from tProjects JOIN tOrderDetails
         on tOrderDetails.ProjectID = tProjects.ID
       where tOrderDetails.OrderID = tOrders.OrderID) >= @startDate
```

Comment: Joins? Create test tables and play around. You can often get the same result in 3 or 4 ways! Since different dbms products may optimize in different ways, it's a good idea to specify dbms used.

Comment: Thanks jarlh.  I just clarified the question a bit.  Any suggestions for performance increase alternatives other than JOINs?  Transact-SQL.

Comment: Do you want the FIRST ProjectReleaseDt where >= @startDate?  Your query isn't asking for that but I'm guessing that is what you want?  EDIT: I guess you don't as you're not returning the value in the select... ignore me...

Comment: @Drammy Yes, otherwise it may return multiple times depending on how many items are in tOrderDetails.   We needed that to avoid the multiple value error when evaluating the  >=@startDate

Comment: Please clarify something for me. You want the total charges of all orders with at least one project associated through an order detail that has a release date on or after the specified start date. BUT...ignore the entire order if any order detail associated with the order is a promo. Does that about wrap it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think `EXISTS` may have the best performance, you might also consider the following approach. When you mention in your question that your query has "unwanted results of adding tOrderDetails fields multiple times" it's probably because you have multiple tOrderDetail records so you need to collapse them with a `GROUP BY`. Rather than using a correlated sub-query which is very inefficient, use a single sub-query with `INNER JOIN` like this.

```
   SELECT
    sum (cast(Replace(tOrders.TotalCharges, '$', '') as money)) as TotalCharges
    FROM [ArtistShare].[dbo].tOrders
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT OrderID
            FROM tOrderDetails d INNER JOIN tProjects p on d.ProjectID = p.ID
            WHERE d.isPromo = 0 AND p.ProjectReleaseDt > @startDate
            GROUP BY OrderID
        ) qualifyingOrders ON qualifyingOrders.OrderID = tOrders.OrderID
    WHERE  tOrders.isGiftCardRedemption = 0
        and tOrders.isTestOrder=0
        and tOrders.LastDateUpdate between @startDate and @endDate
```

Again, you should compare this with the **EXISTS** approach to see  which one performs better and makes the most sense for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The INNER JOIN solution with the added Group by is actually much faster in this case.  (down to 35 seconds from 56).  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why do you count records if you just want to know if at least one *exists* or *not exists*?

```
SELECT     Sum (Cast(Replace(tOrders.TotalCharges, '$', '') AS MONEY)) AS TotalCharges 
FROM       [ArtistShare].[dbo].tOrders 
WHERE      tOrders.isGiftCardRedemption = 0 
AND        tOrders.isTestOrder = 0 
AND        tOrders.LastDateUpdate BETWEEN @startDate AND  @endDate 
AND        NOT EXISTS 
           ( 
                  SELECT 1 FROM   tORderDetails 
                  WHERE  tORderDetails.ORderID = tORders.ORderID 
                  AND    tOrderDetails.isPromo = 1 ) 
AND        EXISTS 
           ( 
                  SELECT 1 FROM   tProjects INNER JOIN   tOrderDetails 
                  ON     tOrderDetails.ProjectID = tProjects.ID 
                  WHERE  tOrderDetails.OrderID = tOrders.OrderID 
                  AND    tProjects.ProjectReleaseDt >= @startDate )
```

Comment: Good question!  It was simply to create a value to evaluate.  Do  you think EXISTS will give us better performance?  I will try now.

Comment: @redoc: of course, `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` are more efficient. They dont need to evaluate all records but only until the condition is satisfied, so maybe a look at the first record is already sufficient

Comment: @redoc `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` allow the query engine to use indexes and describes what you actually want, so it should perform much better.  It *may* be more performant to use non-correlated `IN` subqueries, but SQL Server will often plan those out the same and `NOT IN` can have unexpected results with `NULL` values.

Comment: @Tim.  Just tested it.  The EXISTS actually gives us the exact same performance time.   (56 seconds ).   I am guessing because the subqueries are already indexed.

Answer (score 0):

One additional approach you could try is to put your sub-query data in to temporary tables first and then query on those.

Obviously I don't have your data or understand the data relationships exactly but hopefully the example below will get you on your way to the correct query for your needs.

Worth comparing the performance at least.

```
DECLARE @ORDERDETAILS TABLE
(
    INT idCount,
    INT orderId
)
INSERT INTO
    @ORDERDETAILS
SELECT
    COUNT(tORderDetails.ID),
    tORderDetails.ORderID
WHERE
    tOrderDetails.isPromo = 1
GROUP BY
    tORderDetails.ORderID

DECLARE @PROJECTS TABLE
(
    DATETIME releaseDte,
    INT orderId
)
INSERT INTO
    @PROJECTS
SELECT
    tProjects.ProjectReleaseDt,
    tOrderDetails.OrderID
FROM 
    tProjects JOIN tOrderDetails ON tOrderDetails.ProjectID = tProjects.ID

SELECT 
    sum (cast(Replace(tOrders.TotalCharges,'$','') as money)) as TotalCharges
FROM 
    [ArtistShare].[dbo].tOrders JOIN @ORDERDETAILS ON @ORDERDETAILS.orderId = tORders.ORderID
        JOIN @PROJECTS ON @PROJECTS.orderId = tOrders.OrderID)
WHERE tOrders.isGiftCardRedemption = 0
  and tOrders.isTestOrder=0
  and tOrders.LastDateUpdate between @startDate and @endDate
  AND @ORDERDETAILS.idCount = 0
  --and (SELECT count(tORderDetails.ID)
  --     from tORderDetails
  --     where tORderDetails.ORderID = tORders.ORderID
  --       and tOrderDetails.isPromo=1) = 0
  AND @PROJECTS.releaseDte >= @startDate --NOT QUITE SURE WHAT THIS EXACTLY MIMICS WHAT YOU ARE TRYING TO DO BUT IF NOT YOU COULD REMOVE THE JOIN AND SUB-QUERY AS FOLLOWS
  --AND (SELECT TOP 1 @PROJECTS.releaseDte WHERE PROJECTS.orderId = tOrders.OrderID) >= @startDate
  --and (SELECT top 1 tProjects.ProjectReleaseDt
  --     from tProjects JOIN tOrderDetails
  --       on tOrderDetails.ProjectID = tProjects.ID
  --     where tOrderDetails.OrderID = tOrders.OrderID) >= @startDate
```